# substring + get words around a keyword

Tags: r

If I have a string:

```
moon <- "The cow jumped over the moon with a silver plate in its mouth"
```

Is there a way I can extract the words in the neighborhood of `"moon"`. Neighborhood could be 2 or 3 words around "moon".

So if my

```
"The cow jumped over the moon with a silver plate in its mouth"
```

I want my output only to be:

```
"jumped over the moon with a silver"
```

I know I can use `str_locate` if I wanted to extract by characters, but not sure how I could do it using "words". Can this be done in R?

Thanks & Regards,
Simak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strsplit`:

```
x <- strsplit(str, " ")[[1]]
i <- which(x == "moon")
paste(x[seq(max(1, (i-2)), min((i+2), length(x)))], collapse= " ")
```

Comment: Sorry for the nasty edit, but I can't think of a better way to take care of end scenarios ending in error due to negative indexing or NA due to accessing outside the vector. Feel free to modify/edit.

Comment: Thanks Arun and Hong. Both approaches worked for a lot of cases and both failed for one particular case which I'm trying to identify and figure out. For this specific case, the entire paragraph was extracted instead of the neighbors. I'm trying to isolate and figure it out. Will keep you posted. Thanks again!

Comment: Simak, It'd be nice if you share the example (by editing your question) to see why it breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
keyword <- "moon"
lookaround <- 2
pattern <- paste0("([[:alpha:]]+ ){0,", lookaround, "}", keyword, 
                "( [[:alpha:]]+){0,", lookaround, "}")

regmatches(str, regexpr(pattern, str))[[1]]
# [1] "The cow jumped over"
```

The idea: Search for *any character followed by a space* occurring a minimum of 0 times and a maximum of "lookaround" (here 2) times, then followed by "keyword" (here "moon"), then followed by *space and bunch of characters pattern repeated between 0 and "lookaround" times*. The `regexpr` function gives the start and stop of this pattern. `regmatches` that wraps this function then fetches the sub-string from this start/stop positions.

Note: `regexpr` can be replaced with `gregexpr` if you want to search for more than 1 occurrence of the same pattern.

---

#### Here's benchmarking on big data comparing Hong's with this answer:

```
str <- "The cow jumped over the moon with a silver plate in its mouth" 
ll <- rep(str, 1e5)
hong <- function(str) {
    str <- strsplit(str, " ")
    sapply(str, function(y) {
        i <- which(y=="moon")
        paste(y[seq(max(1, (i-2)), min((i+2), length(y)))], collapse= " ")
    })
}

arun <- function(str) {
    keyword <- "moon"
    lookaround <- 2
    pattern <- paste0("([[:alpha:]]+ ){0,", lookaround, "}", keyword, 
                    "( [[:alpha:]]+){0,", lookaround, "}")

    regmatches(str, regexpr(pattern, str))
}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(t1 <- hong(ll), t2 <- arun(ll), times=10)
# Unit: seconds
#            expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  t1 <- hong(ll) 6.172986 6.384981 6.478317 6.654690 7.193329    10
#  t2 <- arun(ll) 1.175950 1.192455 1.200674 1.227279 1.326755    10

identical(t1, t2) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I guess you'd need to build that pattern with `paste` if `keyword` is a variable.

Comment: Thanks Arun and GSee for responding. GSee, you are right, the keyword will be a variable..and I'll have to build the pattern I suppose. Is regmatches preferred over strsplit?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using the `tm` package (when all you've got is a hammer...)

```
moon <- "The cow jumped over the moon with a silver plate in its mouth"

require(tm)
my.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(moon))
# Tokenizer for n-grams and passed on to the term-document matrix constructor
library(RWeka)
neighborhood  <- 3 # how many words either side of word of interest
neighborhood1 <- 2 + neighborhood  * 2 
ngramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = neighborhood1, max = neighborhood1))
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(my.corpus, control = list(tokenize = ngramTokenizer))
inspect(dtm)

#  find ngrams that have the word of interest in them
word <- 'moon'
subset_ngrams <- dtm$dimnames$Terms[grep(word, dtm$dimnames$Terms)]

# keep only ngrams with the word of interest in the middle. This
# removes duplicates and lets us see what's on either side
# of the word of interest

subset_ngrams <- subset_ngrams[sapply(subset_ngrams, function(i) {
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(i, split=" "))
  tmp <- tmp[length(tmp) - span]
  tmp} == word)]

# inspect output
subset_ngrams
[1] "jumped over the moon with a silver plate"
```